# Using curl to get a specific value from Plesk Remote API (REST)

Tags: curl, plesk

I use curl to get a DNS record from my Plesk server:

`curl -X GET -H 'authorization: Basic xxx' -H 'accept: application/json' 'https://example.com:8443/api/v2/dns/records/15781/'`

result:

```
{
    "id": 15781,
    "type": "A",
    "host": "home.example.com",
    "value": "123.123.123.123",
    "opt": "",
    "ttl": 600
}
```

But what if I only want `123.123.123.123`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

Try this:

```
curl -s -X GET -H 'authorization: Basic xxx' -H 'accept: application/json' 'https://example.com:8443/api/v2/dns/records/15781/' | jq '.value'
```

See more in the [documentation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Basicfilters).

Comment: I'm not sure what just happened.

-bash: jq: command not found
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    23    0    23    0     0    149      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   151
(23) Failed writing body

Comment: You need to install jq first.

Comment: lol, I figured from looking at the documentation.

but unfortunately the result isn't very different.

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    23    0    23    0     0    143      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   144
null

Comment: I didn't checked your curl command; you showed JSON, I provided a way to parse JSON. So well, you need to suppress curl's progress bar by adding `--silent` (answer updated).

Comment: 2 months later and I finally got back to this. @NikitaKipriyanov your answer worked perfectly, thank you.